# matrix representation of this quotient map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F[x]$ be the vector space of polynomials over the field $F$. Define $L(f(x))= x^2 f(x)$. Let $x^n F[x]$ be all polynomials divisible by $x^n$. Then I know that $L$ induces a map of quotients $\overline{L}= F[x]/x^n F[x] \rightarrow F[x]/x^n F[x]$. What I have trouble with is finding the matrix representation of $\overline{L}$.

---

This is what I have worked out so far:

$F[x]$ has basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,...\}$

$x^n F[x]$ has basis $\{x^n, x^{n+1},...\}$

Hence, $F[x]/x^n F[x]$ has basis $\{1+ x^n F[x],\ x+ x^n F[x],\ x^2 + x^n F[x], ...,\ x^{n-1} + x^n F[x]\}$

So, for all $k$ such that $n-3 \geq k \geq 0$,

$\begin{aligned}
\ \overline{L}(x^k + x^n F[x]) &= L(x^k) + x^n F[x]\\
&= x^{k+2} + x^n F[x] 
\end{aligned} $

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & ? & ? \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & ? & ? \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & ? & ? \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & ? & ? \\
 & & & \vdots & & &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & ? & ?
\end{pmatrix}

However, what would the value be for $k = n-2$ and $k = n-1$?

Answer (score 0):

Their values are $0$, and so all the ? in you matrix are $0$. Your computation shows for example $$\overline{L}(x^{n-2} + x^nF[x])=x^n + x^nF[x] = x^nF[x] = 0 + x^n$$ Same for $k=n-1$, since then you get the image of it under $\overline{L}$ is $x^{n+1} + x^nF[x]$. The point is $x^n$ and $x^{n+1}$ are divisible by $x^n$, so they are in $x^nF[x]$.